# What is the order of execution with coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Consider the following code in kotlin.

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job())
scope.launch {
   println("inside coroutine")
}
println("outside coroutine")
```

We create a coroutine in the Main(UI) thread and there is some code after the coroutine.
I know it doesn´t make much sense to do that in real code, but it´s just a theoretical question.

Considering that the coroutine runs in the Main thread, why ***println("outside coroutine")*** is ALWAYS executed first?
I would have expected that sometimes i would see first ***outside coroutine*** and other times, first ***inside coroutine***, kind of like two threads.
Who (OS or Coroutines implementation) decides that the coe outside the coroutine is run first?

Comment: `Dispatchers.Main` runs on main looper. Any coroutine `launch`ed on it will be queued for execution so it will always run later since main looper will have other "stuff" to do first (lifecycle methods, ui callbacks, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering that the coroutine runs in the Main thread, why println("outside coroutine") is ALWAYS executed first?

Let's imagine that your code instead was this:

```
someView.post {
   println("inside post")
}
println("outside post")
```

Here, we create a `Runnable` (lambda expression) and pass that to `post()` on some `View`. `post()` says that the `Runnable` will be `run()` on the main application thread... eventually. That `Runnable` is put on the work queue that the `Looper` powering the main application thread uses, and it gets executed when that `Runnable` gets to the top of the queue (more or less — the details are messier IIRC but not important here).

But if you are executing this code on the main application thread, `println("outside post")` will always be printed first. The `Runnable` is placed onto the queue to be executed later, but you are still executing on the main application thread, and so even if the queue were empty, that `Runnable` will not run until you return control of the main application thread back to Android. So, after the call to `post()`, execution continues with `println("outside post")`.

Under the covers, `Dispatchers.Main` is basically using `post()` (again, the details are more complicated but not too important for this discussion). So, when you `launch()` the coroutine, that lambda expression gets queued up to be executed eventually on the main application. But, you are already on the main application thread, so execution continues normally, and the `println("outside post")` gets printed before the coroutine gets a chance to do anything.

Suppose that your code instead was:

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job())
scope.launch {
   println("inside coroutine")
}
scope.launch {
   println("inside another coroutine")
}
```

Now you are in a situation where in theory either of those lines could be printed first. You are queuing up both lambda expressions, and it is up to the dispatcher to decide what to run on what thread at what point. In practice, it would not surprise me if "inside coroutine" is always printed first, as a simple implementation of `Dispatchers.Main` would use FIFO ordering in the absence of other constraints (e.g., a coroutine is blocked on I/O). However, you should not assume a particular order of invocation of those two coroutines.

Comment: For completeness, there's  also the (now deprecated) option `CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED`, which will cause the launched coroutine to start executing immediately and cede control to the parent coroutine only when it encounters a suspension point. This is once again deterministic behavior, but it shows that the late start of the coroutine is not fundamental.