# Why and how Kotlin coroutine prevents blocking of a thread, even without "suspend" keyword?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I came across some unexpected behavior while using coroutines in Android app.

Suppose I've got the following function, which is not "suspend". It starts worker threads and should block the calling thread until all workers terminate:

```
fun doSomething() : Result {

    // producers init thread
    Thread {
        for (i in 0 until NUM_OF_MESSAGES) {
            startNewProducer(i) // each producer is a thread
        }
    }.start()

    // consumers init thread
    Thread {
        for (i in 0 until NUM_OF_MESSAGES) {
            startNewConsumer() // each consumer is a thread
        }
    }.start()


    synchronized(lock) {
        while (numOfFinishedConsumers < NUM_OF_MESSAGES) {
            try {
                (lock as java.lang.Object).wait()
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                return@synchronized
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized(lock) {
        return Result(
                System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimestamp,
                numOfReceivedMessages
        )
    }

}
```

I know that `(lock as java.lang.Object).wait()` is ugly and I'd be better off with ReentrantLock, but I intentionally wanted to fall to the most primitive level.

Now, if I execute this function without coroutine from Android's main thread, it blocks the calling thread (expected behavior):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    someObject.doSomething()
}
```

However, if I just wrap it in a coroutine which is also executed on main thread, main thread isn't blocked anymore, but the functionality remains the same:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        val result = someObject.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1. I thought that in order for coroutines to work, the functions should be "suspend", but it's not the case here. So, what's the point of "suspend" then?
2. Call to `(lock as java.lang.Object).wait()` should've blocked the main thread. How comes it doesn't when coroutine is involved? Do coroutines have a mean of "intercepting" such low level interactions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use `findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).post { val result = someObject.doSomething() }`? `launch()`, like `post()`, sets up work to be done on the main application thread in the future, so the rest of the current callback can proceed (i.e., the rest of `onCreate()` in your case). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58442375/115145) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yep, you're right. I looked into it further, and the main thread is indeed blocked. It's just that animations still work, so it made it look like everything is alive and led me to ask this question.
So, it's not related to coroutines. Can you please post a short answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like `post()` on a `View`, `launch()` (usually) schedules work to be performed asynchronously with respect to the current bit of execution. So, the code in your lambda expression passed to `launch()` will be run on the main application thread eventually, just as the `Runnable` that you supply to `post()` will be run on the main application thread eventually. However, your `onCreate()` function will continue past the point of `launch()` to do whatever else it is supposed to.

However, just like a `Runnable` passed to `post()` could still tie up the main application thread due to what work it does in `run()`, your coroutine could still tie up the main application thread. It's just that this work would happen later than it would if you did the work directly in `onCreate()`.

> It's just that animations still work

IIRC, on newer versions of Android, animations themselves get processed on a separate "render" thread.

Comment: You are right, they get processed on Render thread. Its state can be easily tracked using CPU profiler, it should be visible alongside the main thread.